# Is there a way to make the compiler copy-paste entire methods for performance?

Tags: performance, c#

I ran a quick benchmark and the overhead from calling methods is not small, especially if you have to do so hundreds of times per second.

I have been making several applications that need to run often more than a hundred times per second, so instead of making different methods when code is repeated, I just copy paste the code everywhere to avoid the overhead.

Is there a way to make the compiler do this for certain methods without me having to copy paste code everywhere? Is this even a smart thing to do and what alternatives are there to avoid branching to methods?

Comment: Method inlining?

Comment: Absolutely, thank you! One can inline methods in C# using the attribute: [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)] .